# How to hook into all Android click events?

Tags: android

I'm looking for a relatively simple method of hooking into all click events in already existing code. Whenever a click occurs, I want the already assigned click event handler to run, and then I want to run the additional click handler that will do whatever I need it to do. Essentially, I want a simple way of adding a new OnClickListener to everything that can  accept it.

```
For each component c
  add extra OnClickListener to c
```

Comment: I doubt there's a simple way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no notion of an "extra" listener for these sorts of events -- there is only one per widget.

You could create your own `CompositeOnClickListener` that holds onto 1+ `OnClickListener` objects and passes click events to all of them. However, there is no `getOnClickListener()` method on `View`, so there would be no way for you to apply it across the board.

Hence, as @Falmarri indicates, I doubt that this is really possible.

Comment: This is what I was afraid to hear.  I guess I'll have to look into alternative options.  Thanks.

Comment: four yrs later, did you ever get any headway in this area....? came across this recently looks like momentum in this regards....http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/plugins/RxJavaObservableExecutionHook.html

Comment: @sirvon: Well, there can be no "headway", insofar as there is still only one listener per event per widget. I'm sure somebody has set up composite listeners, whether reactive or otherwise.